# What function constructor returns in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I came accross with a question #83 in
https://github.com/lydiahallie/javascript-questions

```
function Car() {
  this.make = 'Lamborghini';
  return { make: 'Maserati' };
}

const myCar = new Car();
console.log(myCar.make);
```

To my understanding the code should log `'Lamborghini'`and `conso;e.log(myCar().make)` should log `'Maserati'`
But I'm totally wrong, `myCar` is not a function. Why?

Comment: "*But I'm totally wrong, myCar is not a function. Why?*" because it's an object. `new Car()` never returns a function here.

Comment: @VLAZ okay. If I take away ```return { make: 'Maserati' };``` then the code logs ```'Lamborghini'```. I don't understand how ```return``` affects what is returned by ```New``` statement.

Comment: It replaces it, as long as it's an object.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use your function as a constructor you don't need to return anything from it. When you invoke your function with `new` keyword Javascript will create a new object under the hood, bind it to `this` and return it by default

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question. OP is asking how a given code behaves, not what modification to make to the code.